# Interpolation and restructuring data with R

Tags: r, interpolation

**Background:**

Construction events take place on a certain block of road. The events are based on data like Lane#, Layer#, and SP and EP (Start Position and End Position).

I created a picture to make it easier to visualize
[image]

Now there are two things you can do to a specific layer in a lane:

1. Get rid of some material
2. Add some material

The entire layer for a lane is not made in one day, so on day 1 they could put together layer 4 from SP=0 to EP=75 and so on and so forth.

**Data:**

The data that I have looks like this:

```
Lane#|Activity|Date       |Layer#|SP |EP |Start_Thick|End_Thick  
1    |Add     |10/17/2000 |1     |0  |150|0          |0  
1    |Add     |10/17/2000 |2     |0  |150|12         |12  
1    |Add     |10/17/2000 |3     |0  |150|10.5       |10.5   
1    |Add     |10/17/2000 |4     |0  |150|2          |2  
1    |Add     |10/17/2000 |5     |0  |100|2          |2  
1    |Add     |10/17/2000 |5     |100|150|2          |3  
1    |Sub     |10/20/2000 |5     |0  |125|-1         |-1  
1    |Sub     |10/20/2000 |5     |125|150|-1         |-1.5  
1    |Add     |10/20/2000 |6     |0  |50 |2          |2  
1    |Add     |10/20/2000 |6     |50 |150|2          |2
```

**Result:**

The result I want to get when I say get me a snapshot for Lane 1 at SP>=0 and EP<=150 is this:

```
Lane#|Layer#|SP |EP |Start_Thick|End_Thick  
1    |1     |0  |150|0          |0  
1    |2     |0  |150|12         |12  
1    |3     |0  |150|10.5       |10.5   
1    |4     |0  |150|2          |2  
1    |5     |0  |100|1          |1  <<
1    |5     |100|125|1          |1.5  <<
1    |5     |125|150|1.5        |1.5    <<   
1    |6     |0  |50 |2          |2  
1    |6     |50 |150|2          |2
```

Layer 5 can be explained like this:
[image]

The first two entries in the original table shows the addition of materials and the latter two shows removal from different positions. I have not tried to interpolate before with R so I am not sure if this is possible or not but I would appreciate any help.

I might have missed some information so feel free to ask for additional details if needed.

**DPUT:**

```
structure(list(laneid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), Activity = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Add", "Sub"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(971755200, 
971755200, 971755200, 971755200, 971755200, 971755200, 1129780800, 
1129780800, 1129780800, 1129780800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), Layerid = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L), sp = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 0L, 125L, 0L, 50L), ep = c(150L, 
150L, 150L, 150L, 100L, 150L, 125L, 150L, 50L, 150L), Start_Thick = c(0, 
12, 10.5, 2, 2, 2, -1, -1, 2, 2), End_Thick = c(0, 12, 10.5, 
2, 2, 3, -1, -1.5, 2, 2)), .Names = c("laneid", "Activity", "Date", 
"Layerid", "sp", "ep", "Start_Thick", "End_Thick"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This sounds like you want to filter based on two conditions . . . what are you trying to interpolate?

Comment: @BenG The result table calculates the actual thickness for a specific layer within certain start and end positions. If the layer is created from 0-100 and then 100 to 150. Afterwards, some material is taken off from 0-125. Now, I don't know the thickness at 125, so I would interpolate based on 100 to 150 and then do the calculation on that number

Comment: What interpolation method do you want to use?

Comment: @BenG Linear interpolation

Comment: I guess what's not clear from your question is which values you need to interpolate.  I think you would need another column indicating if that value was missing because it's not intuitively clear what needs to be interpolated.  Also, if you use `dput` to post a reproducible example of your data it'd be easier to help.

Comment: @BenG I have added the dput data. The interpolation logic should be to check if the Sub activity mileposts match exactly with the Add activity mileposts, if not that would mean that interpolation is required. If adding another column would help, I am open to the idea.

Comment: You can use the `approx` function to interpolate values, but it doesn't really seem like what you're after.  It looks like you want the mean value between the two columns but I'm not sure . . .